# Android augmented reality. Bad sensors reading

Tags: android, augmented-reality

First of all, sorry for my english. I'm programming an Augmented Reality Browser for Android following the steps in Raghav Sood's book. Its title is Pro Android Augmented Reality. The thing is that when i launch the example of chapter 9 (named Pro Android AR 9 and located in https://github.com/RaghavSood/ProAndroidAugmentedReality) in my devices, it works fine or not depending on the kind of device.

In my Sony Ericsson Xperia Arc with Android 4.0.4 the browser implemented by Raghav works really fine. When i test the augmented-reality browser in Asus Eee Pad Transformer or in Samsung Galaxy Tab, both of them with Android 4.0.3, the readings from the sensors seem to be wrong. Holding the tablets in landscape mode in front of me, if i focus over one spot (wikipedia, twitter or local markers) and turn over myself to the right, the spots goes down. If i turn to the left, the spots goes up. If i want the spots to move to the left, i have to tilt the devices  making their screens look to the ground. In the same order, if i turn the devices making the screens look up to the air, the spots will move to the right.

Seems like the program is confusing sensor readings. Anyone knows how to solve the problem??? Thanks in advance.

Comment: (I'm the author of the book in question) Hmm. AFAIK, this shouldn't be happening. However, it is possible that since you're using tablets, the values the sensors report are inverted by Android as the device's natural orientation is landscape. I will try to find a tablet and push a bugfix to the github repository. In the meantime, see if flipping the axis values in the code works.

Comment: I will try. Thanks Raghvad, your book is really interesting. Great job.

Comment: Thank you! Hope you find it helpful

Comment: That's great! You should add that as an answer to your question, and accept it as the solution. I'll look into merging this into the main code with a check to see what the natural orientation of the device is when I have some free time

Comment: i cannot answer my question because this is the first question ive made =(. Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You can answer in 5 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead.

Comment: i made it. I don't know if it is a good solution but seems to work fine on tablets. 

Changing the axis to SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(temp, SensorManager.AXIS_X, SensorManager.AXIS_Y, rotation) in SensorActivity seems to fix the axis malfunction. Other problem was that the text asociated with each POI appeared turned in tablets using landscape mode. To avoid this, i used a conditional rotation modification in set method of PaintablePosition class: if(drawObj.toString().toLowerCase().contains("paintableboxedtext")) rotation=rotation+270;

Comment: Answer it in 5 hours then. I'm glad you managed to get it working

Comment: it was easier with your indications. Thanks Raghav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i made it. I don't know if it is a good solution but seems to work fine on tablets.

Changing the axis to:

```
SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(temp, SensorManager.AXIS_X, SensorManager.AXIS_Y, rotation)
```

in SensorActivity seems to fix the axis malfunction. Other problem was that the text asociated with each POI appeared turned in tablets using landscape mode. To avoid this, i used a conditional rotation modification in set method of PaintablePosition class:

```
if(drawObj.toString().toLowerCase().contains("paintableboxedtext")) rotation=rotation+270;
```